# Django page not saving data correctly

Tags: python, django, post, request

I have a form in a HTML page that I'm using for a Django project. This form takes the input from the user and sends it to a page which should save it to the database, but right now its not doing do. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create product here</h2>
<div>
<form id="new_user_form" method="post" action="user/create"}>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
  <label for="name" > Name:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
  <label for="description"> description:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="description"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="price" > price:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="price"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from testapp import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('user/create', views.create_user, name='create_user')
]
```

The views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testapp.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        price = request.POST.get('price')

        newUser = User(
            name = name,
            description = description,
            price = price
        )

        newUser.save()

        return HttpResponse('')
```

And the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null = True)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True)
```

Now the problem is when the form data gets sent to the function create_user, it should take the data and create a object with that data and save it to the database. The database is set up correctly as when I use the Django shell to test it, users are created and saved. However, through the form and the python, something is going wrong here and I'm not sure why. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I'd recommend that you take a look at [Django documentation regarding forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/). This will give you a better way of approaching your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the name in the inputs html tags

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" id="description" name="description"/>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
```

Comment: Changed it to this, didnt fix the problem.